Let $x,y,z$ and $a,b,c$ be integers where $a,b,c$ are distinct integers $\ge{2}$, then show that the equation $x^a+y^b=z^c$ has no integer solution.
Progress:
Let $x,y,z$ and $a,b,c$ be integers where $a,b,c$ are distinct integers $\ge{2}$, then show that the equation $x^a+y^b=z^c$ has no integer solution.

Consider for example, $x^3+y^5=z^{10}$ or $x^2+y^7=z^9$ and so on, my conjecture is that no such equation has an integer solution providing the condition mentioned. Now how can I prove/disprove that? I tried myself so hard but didn't succeed. So any help or insight would be helpful and appreciated.


You would require a non-zero solution, right? Otherwise, take $a$ whatever and take $b=2$, $c=4$, then $(x,y,z) = (0,d^2,d)$ is a solution for all $d$.

Assuming that the OP asked for where $x,y,z \geq 2$ and $a,b,c \geq 3$, this is currently known as the Beal Conjecture. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal_conjecture)

In fact, it seems that there are non-zero counterexamples as well, such as $a=$whatever, $b=3$ and $c=2$ has $(x,y,z)=(1,2,3)$ as a solution.

@AaaLol_dude Well spotted. Stated as above, it is not directly a generalization of Fermat and slightly weaker than the Beal conjecture, but knowing Fermat they are equivalent (if OP had the right assumptions). Also, OP requires $a,b,c$ to be distinct, so Pythagorean triples are not counterexamples.

@SomeCallMeTim Yes, I have just realised that.

Isn't it also necessary that $x,y$ are coprime for the Beal conjecture ? I might be wrong , but I think there are nontrivial solutions if we omit this condition.

Quasi-trivial counterexample: $4^a+2^{2a}=2^{2a+1}$, or more generally $(2^n)^a+2^{na}=2^{na+1}$

Disprove:$$46^2+3^4=13^3$$
So not only $a,\ b,\ c$ are integers $\ge 2$, but also $x,\ y,\ z$.

Thanks for your answer.
